# No space after inline math

Tags: spacing

how do I prevent (at least nearly) any space after an inline math environment?

```
abc def $\Delta$ ghi
```

The space between the delta and *ghi* shouldn't be larger than the space between *abc* and *def*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is just one word space after `c` after `f` and after the math, in each case coming from the space in the source.:

[image]

Comment: it may just look bigger because of the shape of the delta.

Answer (score 11):

The spaces can be debugged with `\showlists` or putting the text in a box with `\showbox`:

```
...
\showlists
% or
\sbox0{...}
\showbox0
```

Then TeX prints the current contributions to the vertical list or the box contents to the `.log` file. The amount of the data is controlled by the
parameters `\showboxbreadth` and `\showboxdepth` that should be increased, because the default is negative for both of them to suppress the output.
`\tracingonline=1` also writes the `.log` messages to the console.

```
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \sbox0{abc def $\Delta$ ghi}
  \showbox0
  \usebox0
\end{document}
```

LaTeX stops at `\showbox` to print the box contents to the console/`.log` file:

> [image: Result]
>
> ```
> > \box0=
> \hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x60.00012
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
> .\kern0.27779
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\mathon
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^A
> .\mathoff
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
>
> ! OK.
> l.8 \showbox0
> ```

As you can see, the three spaces between `abc`, `def`, `Δ` and `ghi` are exact the same (interword space):

```
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
```

Inline math can have space around the formula if `\mathsurround` is set. Its default is zero. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\mathsurround}{1ex}
\begin{document}
  sbox0{abc def $\Delta$ ghi}
  \showbox0
  \usebox0
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Box contents with `\mathsurround=1ex`:

> ```
> > \box0=
> \hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x68.6112
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 a
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 b
> .\kern0.27779
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 c
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 d
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 f
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\mathon, surrounded 4.30554
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^A
> .\mathoff, surrounded 4.30554
> .\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 g
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
> .\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
>
> ! OK.
> l.9 \showbox0
> ```

But there can be other visual effects. TeX only sees the char bounding boxes. It does not know, where the glyph is acutally placed. This can be made visible by using a tight `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}

\begin{document}
  \fbox{abc} \fbox{def} \fbox{$\Delta$} \fbox{ghi}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Observations:**

- As you can see, a part of the `f` is written outside to the right of its bounding box (this is allowed, not a bug). Thus the space between `def` and `Δ` might look a little smaller.
- On the other side of `Δ` the letter `g` has a positive side bearing to the left. Side bearings mean a little space to the left and right of the symbol inside the character bounding box. Also the upper right part of `Δ` and the upper part of `g` are empty. Thus the space looks huge in comparison to the space between `f` and `Δ`.

Comment: +1 nice answer. I hope you don't steal my tick though:-)